# Is 不仅仅 the correct word?

Tags: meaning, word

In the following sentence:

> 这家小资的咖啡店本身**不仅仅**是一间咖啡店，还是首个提出咖啡情绪疗法的品牌。

I know 不仅 means "not only", and 不仅～还是 means "not only ~ but also ~", similar to English idiom.

However, this sentence uses 不仅仅, not 不仅. I wonder if it is a typo, or correct sentence. In that case, what is the difference between 不仅 and 不仅仅?

Comment: see dictionaries：不仅，不仅仅 （both in IME editor) http://hanyu.iciba.com 不仅:①（连）不止；表示超出某个数目或范围。这～是我一个人的主张；也是同志们的心愿。②（连）不但。他～学习好；而且身体也好。bkrs：不仅仅not only 这些歌曲不仅仅在本世纪里流行。他这次来不仅仅是为了工作，也是为了你。[直义] 人不是光靠面包活着; 人活着不仅仅是需要面包; 人活着不光是要吃饭.
[释义] 除物质需要外, 人还有精神需求.＂汉语虚词词典＂：＂不仅仅＂和＂不仅＂一样。Some dictionaries may not have 不仅仅，but they have 仅仅。

Comment: Seriously, I don't quite understand why you keep commenting the OP's post instead of answering. Your contributions are on topic and useful, so why not put them inside a proper answer? Once again: the OP might see your comment because they receive a notification, but other users likely won't bother with comments and jump straight to the answer section. SE sites are just *designed* around this. :)

Comment: @TXV I agree. Also, the comment is hard to read, especially the way he describes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 不仅...而且/还是...  is equivalent to "not only... but also...". I think 不仅仅 fits here. Because the author really wants to emphasize the achievement of this coffee shop, which is '首个提出咖啡情绪疗法的品牌'.

Example:

> 他不仅是一个模特，还是一个大学教授。

This just tells you that he has two jobs.

But if you say,

> 他不仅仅是一个模特,还是一个大学教授

this means that being both a model and a university professor is really impressive.